# split a string on python math comparators

Tags: python, regex

So guys here I am asking trivial questions.
I have this string filterE, I want to break filterE on valid mathematical comparators only.

```
filterE = "x.y.prop1 ==== 1 and x.y.prop2 >= 2 and x.y.prop1 < 3 or x.y.prop4 > 9"
```

I thought of using something like `re.split(r'(=(?=)|<|<(?=)|>|>(?=)|!(?=))', filterE)` but it did not help at all.
Here is my code snippet

```
import re
pfe = re.split(r'(==|<|<=|>|>=|!=)', filterE)

Desired_op>>> ['x.y.prop1 ==== 1 and x.y.prop2', '>=', '2 and x.y.prop1', '<', '3 or x.y.prop4' ,'>' ,'9']

Compiled_op>>> ['x.y.prop1 ', '==', '', '==', ' 1 and x.y.prop2 ', '>', '= 2 and x.y.prop1 ', '<', ' 3 or x.y.prop4 ', '>', ' 9']

pfe = re.split(r'(=(?=)|<|<(?=)|>|>(?=)|!(?=))', filterE)

Compiled_op>>> ['x.y.prop1 ', '=', '', '=', '', '=', '', '=', ' 1 and x.y.prop2 ', '>', '', '=', ' 2 and x.y.prop1 ', '<', ' 3 or x.y.prop4 ', '>', ' 9']
```

I want that filterE should split only on '<=' , '==' ,'>=', '>' ,'<' and '!=' so I made this regex but work properly.

```
pfe = re.split(r'(=(?<==)|<|<(?<==)|>|>(?<==)|!(?<==))', filterE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a negative lookahead and a negative lookbehind to @Anthony's answer

```
>>> import re
>>> filterE = "x.y.prop1====1 and x.y.prop2>=2 and x.y.prop1<3 or x.y.prop4>9"
>>> re.split(r'((?<!=)==(?!=)|<=|>=|!=|<|>)', filterE)
['x.y.prop1====1 and x.y.prop2', '>=', '2 and x.y.prop1', '<', '3 or x.y.prop4', '>', '9']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want that filterE should split only on '<=' , '==' ,'>=', '>' ,'<' and '!=' so I made this regex but it does not work properly.

pfe = re.split(r'(=(?<==)|<|<(?<==)|>|>(?<==)|!(?<==))', filterE)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to improve your re a bit

```
>>> pfe = re.split(r'(==*|<=|>=|!=|<|>)', filterE)
>>> pfe # match your Desired_op
['x.y.prop1 ', '====', ' 1 and x.y.prop2 ', '>=', ' 2 and x.y.prop1 ', '<', ' 3 or x.y.prop4 ', '>', ' 9']
```

Note the placement of '*' and symbols of '<' and '>' in regular expression

Comment: I think `====` is not a valid mathematical comparators.

Comment: I agree. I am just addressing OP's regular expression question.

Comment: I apologize I should have been more clearer but in my Desired_op>>> ['x.y.prop1 ==== 1 and x.y.prop2', '>=', '2 and x.y.prop1', '<', '3 or x.y.prop4' ,'>' ,'9'] .

filterE should not split on '====', or '===' or '=' it should split only on '=='

Comment: @AnthonyKong, you were close. Just need to add a couple of negative assertions around `==`

Comment: @gnibbler Thanks. Looks like you gave a better answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

If your comparators are always surrounded by spaces, simply do

```
re.split(r'\s(==|<|<=|>|>=|!=)\s', filterE)
```

Otherwise, say it looks like:

```
filterE = "x.y.prop1====1 and x.y.prop2>=2 and x.y.prop1<3 or x.y.prop4>9"
```

Then you can use lookahead assertions like:

```
re.split(r'(?<=\s|[^=<>])(==|<|<=|>|>=|!=)(?=\s|[^=<>])', filterE)
# ['x.y.prop1====1 and x.y.prop2', '>=', '2 and x.y.prop1', '<', '3 or x.y.prop4', '>', '9']
```

Comment: works very well for me, but can you point me in right direction for learning more about the regex, as I am not very good at it. And what makes the difference between two syntax's. Any followup answers are not needed but will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan - This is a very good [reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html).  I learned Regex from here.

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan: Always read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)